# Eclipse can’t find XMLGregorianCalendar class - as part of Jakarta migration

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar, jakarta-migration

I have migrated a project from java 1.8 to java 17. The application is a maven project.  Eclipse complains it can't resolve `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`.  I know that in java 11 the java.xml.bind is removed,  which dependency i can use, either xml-apis or jaxb-api-*.jar , is compatible with java 17?

Comment: I thought all packages that start with javax have been removed from JDK 17.   I see OpenJDK and Oracle JDK have that class.  Possible problem with Eclipse.  Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278964/eclipse-cant-find-javax-xml-datatype-xmlgregoriancalendar-java-11

Comment: In my case this was the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719125/jdk-10-cannot-import-javax-xml-namespace-in-eclipse/61387697#61387697