# JDK 11 migration- The type javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-11, java-9

I am using Eclipse IDE 4.16 and migrating the project from JDK 8 to JDK 11.
I am getting the following error while building the project with ANT Script.

> The type javax.xml.namespace.QName cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

[image]

I have tried to remove the dependent JARs by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and searching for the required package.
I have kept only the packages present in JDK 11 and removed the other JARs which were referencing the javax.xml.namespace package as we can see from the following screenshot:

[image]

I tried to follow this link as it was quite similar to my issue but the error was not resolved.

[JDK 10 cannot import javax.xml.namespace in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719125/jdk-10-cannot-import-javax-xml-namespace-in-eclipse)

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Could you please give more information to understand.

Comment: Which compiler is your Ant script using?

Comment: I suppose we are using JAVA 11 compiler for Ant script.