# Why error shows (top down approach) when generating java bean skeleton from wsdl file?

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I am trying to do top down project in eclipse. And evertime I  try to create the Java Bean skeleton from the .wsdl file, I get error as shown in the picture. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbdYe.png). I am not sure what causing that issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error image does only show red underlined from IDE.
Please hover over it or try to compile to get the real error message.

But just guessing.

```
javax.xml.namespace.QName
```

can not get resolved?
Are you using Java 10 or higher?
This package is not included anymore.
Maybe this will help: [JDK 10 cannot import javax.xml.namespace in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719125/jdk-10-cannot-import-javax-xml-namespace-in-eclipse)